# why i have to use print((sender as AnyObject).currentTitle!!) to print title and print(sender.currentTitle) not work?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, swift2

Why when I try to print button title i used `print(sender.currentTitel)` and isn't working.

And this in below it is work:

`print((sender as AnyObject).currentTitle!!)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! The reason that you're having to cast the object in order to print it is because of Optionals. When "unwrapping" optionals you often need to provide a default value, or tell the program what it should "unwrap" the object as. If you do not provide this default value you have to tell the application to force the cast using the "bang" operator `!`. You can learn more about them in the developer docs. They can be useful when writing functions with conditional arguments, for example. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in a `IBAction` function like this:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // print here
    }
```

This is due to the `Any` reference you declare when you create the IBAction. Two solution.

You can modify your IBAction like this:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
    }
```

or test the sender conformance:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            // print(button.titleLabel?.text)
        }
    }
```

- Solution 1 is better if your IBAction is only triggered by button(s)
- Solution 2 may be an approach if your IBAction is used by multiple senders

Cheers